# Map ports so you can access docker running apps from OSX host

Tags: macos, vagrant, docker

I have been playing with Docker for a while (on OSX via Vagrant) which worked really nice. In order to access my apps running in the docker containers I had to setup Vagrant to use static IPs ("private_network" setup).

While this worked well I think the new approach to use boot2docker is a little lighter and more convenient as I can run docker directly in OSX. However, if I run docker with the usual port forwarding I get this error:

```
docker run -p :5672 -p :15672 mikaelhg/docker-rabbitmq
2014/02/09 10:12:47 Error: start: Cannot start container fecd0f0225f49a889e63e9b113bff36305e9b9ab146ada6730d6cfffe9a10e0b: Process could not be started
```

So then if I explicitly map this to a different host port it starts

```
docker run -p 5000:5672 -p 15000:15672 mikaelhg/docker-rabbitmq
```

However I am unable to open this in my OSX host. I am aware that this setup is different to Vagrant as it does not use static IPs but rather NAT but somehow I cannot find proper docs on how I can access my apps from the OSX host.

Can anyone point me to the right docs or give me an example what setup I need to use to get boot2docker setup the portforwarding for me?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question; you would be better off asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using VirtualBox, configure port forwarding like:

```bsh
$ VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port5000,tcp,,5000,,5672"
$ VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "udp-port5000,udp,,5000,,5672"
```

Read more:
http://www.deadcodersociety.org/blog/forwarding-a-range-of-ports-in-virtualbox/
https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4007#issuecomment-34573044

Comment: Or do it via the VirtualBox app... click the virtualbox boxname, click Settings, click Network, click Adapter 1, click Port Forwarding.